# I want to bash a file from server side containing a list to a table in database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been stuck on how to do this task, python is unavailable, all I can do is pl/sql which I only did once. Basically what I'm trying to do is query a file that contains a list to a table in database, this is the format it contains 123-43763-2748, Please help on how to approach/solve this task. Thank you so much

Comment: I need to output the ones that are not found in the table and write them in server side also

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you have a file that contains data (many rows, I presume?) like the one you posted. Now you'd want to store data from file into a table within an Oracle database. Is that correct?

If so, PL/SQL is not the only option you have. If you want to use it, then you'd first have to acquire access to Oracle **directory** (that's an object that points to a filesystem directory, usually located on a database server). To do so, you'll have to talk to DBA, they'll grant privileges to your user. Then you'd write a PL/SQL procedure which uses `UTL_FILE` package, reads the file and inserts values into the database.

Another option - which also includes previously mentioned directory - is to create a **external table**; it just points to the filesystem file which then acts as if it were an ordinary table, so you can easily query it and use it as a source for a simple `INSERT INTO` statement (to store data into the target table).

Then, there's my favourite option - **SQL Loader**, utility that is capable of reading files stored on your own computer (as opposed to previous options), and is really, really fast. You'd create a control file (it says what data to read and where to store those values) and use it with the `sqlldr` executable.

---

That's theory. It is useless to write some dummy code because you didn't explain any details - for example, how does the target table look like (its description), whether you have access to database server or not, were you granted certain privileges (e.g. execute on `utl_file`) etc.

Comment: I actually don't need to store the list into the table, I just want to query the list if it exists there then output the ones that don't exist.

Comment: If "what" exists, actually?  Rows with some column that matches values in the file?  :You are still WAAAYYYY too short on details.

Comment: For example: The table has this column that contains the same format 123-347-543, let's call it ID(column2). I want to bash my list from server side that contains the same format from ID that has a lot of rows in it and I want to output the ones that doesn't exist to the table from the list I have. So basically, query the list to the table then check if they exist, if not then output the ones that doesn't exist to the table from the list.